# What does "という" mean in this context?

Tags: grammar

I cant understand the use of "という" in this sentence.

> 東京案内がしっかりしていて、 最高に便利な街を目指して計画された所**という**気がしました。

I learned some uses of "という" such as "called", "that says", I've seen it being used to define a noun etc. but in this sentence という doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

”～という” is similar to ”that～”(relative pronoun) or ”about～”. It add explanation to the
words.
In your example, ”という” can add ”最高に便利な街を目指して計画された” to ”気”. In English, I got feeling **that** tokyo was planed to be the most convenient city.